# Missing tiles in Sentinel 1 data

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, sentinel-1, sentinel

I am working with VV/VH Sentinel 1 descending data in Google Earth Engine but there are large areas misisng as shown in the screenshot below. The image indicates the mean data from 1-31 August. The issue appears to have started around January 2022.

[image: Link to image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentinel-1B died in Dec. 2021.
https://www.esa.int/Applications/Observing_the_Earth/Copernicus/Sentinel-1/Mission_ends_for_Copernicus_Sentinel-1B_satellite

The pattern in your image looks much like the planned acquisition strategy:

[image]

https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-1/observation-scenario